# How can I use the XPath count expression to evaluate a if statement?

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I'm trying to figure out how to use a Xpath expression to verify that there is only one matching node in an XPath expression.  Here is some sample XML:

```
<a>
  <b>
    <c>X:1 Y:0</c>
    <c>X:1 Y:0</c>
    <c>X:2 Y:0</c>
  </b>
  <b>
    <c>X:1 Y:0</c>
    <c>X:2 Y:0</c>
  </b>
</a>
```

So, I tried code similar to this, but it doesn't work:

```
XPathFactory factory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
XPath xpath = factory.newXPath();
try {           
    XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile( "count(//a/b/c)" ) );
} catch ( XPathExpressionException e ) {
    printErr( e );
}
if ( expr == true ) {
  // edit XML node
}
```

There is supposedly a way for the count expression to return a Boolean = true .  How do I get this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
XPathExpression xpr = xpath.compile("count(//a/b/c)");
System.out.println(xpr.evaluate(n, XPathConstants.NUMBER));

xpr = xpath.compile("count(//a/b/c) = 5");
System.out.println(xpr.evaluate(n, XPathConstants.BOOLEAN));
```

where n is a Node/Element from your document

First prints 5.0, second prints true

Comment: Having some trouble figuring out how to handle the "n" in your example.

Comment: Sorry about that. When you parse the file you get a Document, from that you can use either an XPath expression to get a certain node or just call document.getDocumentElement().
`DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
doc = builder.parse(new File(filename));
Node n = doc.getDocumentElement();`

Answer (score 3):

You've only compiled an XPath expression, you haven't actually evaluated it.

Note that you can evaluate the expression directly using [`XPath.evaluate()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/xpath/XPath.html#evaluate%28java.lang.String,%20org.xml.sax.InputSource%29):

```
result = xpath.evaluate("count(//a/b/c)", input);
```

Or using your pre-compiled `expr`:

```
result = expr.evaluate(input);
```

And that these `evaluate` methods can also take as an additional argument a type, such as [`XPathConstants.BOOLEAN`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/xpath/XPathConstants.html#BOOLEAN).

So this will work, with `input` as an [`InputSource`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/org/xml/sax/InputSource.html) for your XML:

```
XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("count(//a/b/c) = 5");
Object retval = expr.evaluate(input, XPathConstants.BOOLEAN);

if ((Boolean) retval)
    // edit XML node
```

Answer (score 1):

**You may use**:

```
count(//a/b/c) = 1
```

This evaluates to `true()` if and only if `count(//a/b/c)` evaluates to `1` -- `false()` otherwise.

however this may not be efficient (causes the complete evaluation of the XPath expression and counting all the nodes).

**A more efficient XPath expression**:

```
(//a/b/c)[1] and not( (//a/b/c)[2] )
```

Answer (score 0):

how about `//a/b/c[count(*) != 0]`? 
also if i remember XPathExpression returns an Object, which you'll have to convert to a primitive type i.e xpath Number to Double etc.